# Passing values to ko.computed in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been working for a bit  with MVC4 SPA, with knockoutJs,

My problem is I want to pass a value to a ko.computed. Here is my code.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: firms">
<fieldset>
    <legend><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></legend>
    <div data-bind="foreach: $parent.getClients">
        <p>
            <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</div>

self.getClients = ko.computed(function (Id) {
    var filter = Id;
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Clients(), function (item) {
        var fId = item.FirmId();
        return (fId === filter);
    });
});
```

I simply want to display the Firmname as a header, then show the clients below it. 
The function is being called, but Id is undefined (I've tried with 'Firm' as well), if I change:

```
var filter = id;     TO      var filter = 1;
```

It works fine,

So... How do you pass a value to a ko.computed? It doesn't need to be the Id, it can also be the Firm object etc.

Comment: Id should be an observable on your viewmodel. You should just access it from within the computed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Each firm really should be containing a list of clients, but you could use a regular function I think and pass it the firm:

```
self.getClientsForFirm = function (firm) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Clients(), function (item) {
        var fId = item.FirmId();
        return (fId === firm.Id());
    });
});
```

Then in html, $data is the current model, in your case the firm:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.getClientsForFirm($data)">
```

Comment: Tankyou!! This is just what I need :) But Ill also have in mind that I should have the Clients in a list from the start.

Answer (score 8):

Knockout doesn't allow you pass anything to a computed function. That is not what it is for. You could instead just use a regular function there if you'd like.

Another option is to have the data already in the dataset on which you did the first foreach. This way, you don't use `$parent.getClients`, but more like `$data.clients`.

Comment: I wont go with this suggestion atm, but Its something I will have in mind for the future, thanks for the answer about computed.

Comment: no problem. I had the same suggestion to in my answer, but the other answer has examples.